# linux redhat + how to install only the latest kernel rpm under /boot

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, kernel, rhn

installing of errata security kernel rpm ( from redhat sattelite ) on the linux red-hat,

could sometimes - create a diff 2-4 new update kernel under **/boot** ,

the problem here that **/boot** could be nearly %0 availbe space

is it possible to install only the latest rpm kernel and not all the previous  kernels

I am not sure but I found the **installonly_limit** parameter from **/etc/yum.conf**

when we set i**nstallonly_limit=1** , does this mean to install always the latest kernel ?

for example

dose **installonly_limit=1** ,

Tell us to keep to install only the higher rpm kernel release

and ignore installing the other old kernel version?

```
/etc/yum.conf 

installonly_limit=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible: `yum` intentionally manages kernel updates as new installation, rather than true upgrades.

If your `/boot` partition is full, you should first remove oldest kernels (but **not** the one currently running - you can find it issuing `uname -a`) using `yum remove`. After that, you can install the newer kernels.

Comment: I found the 
package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=1 , this tool should remove all the kernels except the current , but what in case grub.conf is wrong - dose this tool will remove the older kernel in spite bad configuration in /etc/grub.conf?

Comment: Each time a old kernel is removed or a new one is installed, `grub.conf` is recreated by `grub2-mkconfig`, which scans the currently-installed kernel under `/boot` and rewrite the grub config file. So, generally even badly damaged  `grub.conf` file can be repaired - simple because they are wiped and recreted from scratch. Anyway, if in doubt, make a backup copy of your current `grub.conf`.

Comment: can we be sure to use the tool - package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=1 , to remove all old kernel except the current ?

Comment: what in case default=1 in grub.conf . dose this know the current according to (uname -r) ?

Comment: I don't use `package-cleanup` very often, and I prefer to clean up kernels manually (when needed). So I can't answer this specific question. For `GRUB_DEFAULT`, give a look at the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Simple-configuration.html)

Comment: `package-cleanup --oldkernels`  does work. Its exclusions of the running kernel or newer kernels make it fairly safe. This does mean you have 2 installed after you update and before you reboot into the new one.

Comment: please see this article - https://www.question-defense.com/2014/05/13/centos-remove-old-kernels   , they opposite to you answer!